# C# Sort ListBox items using ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net

In this program I have to display many media files in a directory (created in a mock text file) and allow the user to select ComboBox items to filter the results shown in the ListBox. I managed to get it to sort alphabetically, but I can't figure out how to sort it numerically.

Example: CarShow, AVI, 723MB, 2019094 (File Name, File Type, File Size, Last Modification Date)

The other 3 ways I want to reorder my ListBox is by File Type, File Size, and Last Modification Date.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1G6o.png)

I want it to skip the first part (the file name) and check the other elements instead. How would I do this?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //  Declare Lists for each of the following: audio, image, document, video
    List<Audio> audioList = new List<Audio>();
    List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
    List<Document> documentList = new List<Document>();
    List<Video> videoList = new List<Video>();

    //  Affiliate class with variable
    Audio currentAudio = new Audio();
    Image currentImage = new Image();
    Document currentDocument = new Document();
    Video currentVideo = new Video();

    //  Declare int variables as 0
    int numAudio = 0;
    int numImage = 0;
    int numDocument = 0;
    int numVideo = 0;
    int numFiles = 0;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile; //To read the file
            string line;            //To hold a line from the file

            //Create a delimiter array
            char[] delim = { ',' };

            //Open the Files.txt file
            inputFile = File.OpenText("Files.txt");

            //Read the lines from the file
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Read a line from the file
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                //Tokenize the line
                string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                //  Check if the first tokenized string contains "Audio"
                if (tokens[0] == "Audio")
                {
                    currentAudio = new Audio();

                    //  Tokenized variables are numbered and parsed
                    currentAudio.Name = tokens[1];
                    currentAudio.Type = tokens[2];
                    currentAudio.Size = tokens[3];
                    currentAudio.LastModification = int.Parse(tokens[4]);
                    currentAudio.Artist = tokens[5];
                    currentAudio.BitRate = int.Parse(tokens[6]);

                    //Add one to the count of the amount of audio files
                    numAudio += 1;
                    //  Add field to created list
                    audioList.Add(currentAudio);
                    //  Send the following fields to the targeted ListBox
                    filesListBox.Items.Add(currentAudio.Name + ", " + currentAudio.Type + ", " + currentAudio.Size + ", " + currentAudio.LastModification);
                }
                //  Check if the first tokenized string contains "Media"
                else if (tokens[0] == "Media")
                {
                    //  Check if the first tokenized string contains "Video"
                    if (tokens[1] == "Video")
                    {
                        currentVideo = new Video();

                        //  Tokenized variables are numbered and parsed
                        currentVideo.Name = tokens[2];
                        currentVideo.Type = tokens[3];
                        currentVideo.Size = tokens[4];
                        currentVideo.LastModification = int.Parse(tokens[5]);
                        currentVideo.Director = tokens[6];
                        currentVideo.Producer = tokens[7];

                        //Add one to the count of the amount of audio files
                        numVideo += 1;
                        //  Add field to created list
                        videoList.Add(currentVideo);
                        //  Send the following fields to the targeted ListBox
                        filesListBox.Items.Add(currentVideo.Name + ", " + currentVideo.Type + ", " + currentVideo.Size + ", " + currentVideo.LastModification);
                    }
                    //  Check if the first tokenized string contains "Image"
                    else if (tokens[1] == "Image")
                    {
                        currentImage = new Image();

                        //  Tokenized variables are numbered and parsed
                        currentImage.Name = tokens[2];
                        currentImage.Type = tokens[3];
                        currentImage.Size = tokens[4];
                        currentImage.LastModification = int.Parse(tokens[5]);
                        currentImage.Width = decimal.Parse(tokens[6]);
                        currentImage.Height = decimal.Parse(tokens[7]);
                        currentImage.Resolution = tokens[8];

                        //Add one to the count of the amount of audio files
                        numImage += 1;
                        //  Add field to created list
                        imageList.Add(currentImage);
                        //  Send the following fields to the targeted ListBox
                        filesListBox.Items.Add(currentImage.Name + ", " + currentImage.Type + ", " + currentImage.Size + ", " + currentImage.LastModification);
                    }
                }
                //  Check if the first tokenized string contains "Document"
                else if (tokens[0] == "Document")
                {
                    currentDocument = new Document();

                    //  Tokenized variables are numbered and parsed
                    currentDocument.Name = tokens[1];
                    currentDocument.Type = tokens[2];
                    currentDocument.Size = tokens[3];
                    currentDocument.LastModification = int.Parse(tokens[4]);
                    currentDocument.NumPages = int.Parse(tokens[5]);
                    currentDocument.NumWords = int.Parse(tokens[6]);
                    currentDocument.DocSubject = tokens[7];

                    //Add one to the count of the amount of audio files
                    numDocument += 1;
                    //  Add field to created list
                    documentList.Add(currentDocument);
                    filesListBox.Items.Add(currentDocument.Name + ", " + currentDocument.Type + ", " + currentDocument.Size + ", " + currentDocument.LastModification);
                }
            }
            //  Close file
            inputFile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display an error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Call method ReadFile when the form loads
        ReadFile();

        //  Field numFiles is equivalent to its many attributes
        numFiles = (numAudio + numImage + numDocument + numVideo);
        //  Declare TextBox location for the field numFiles
        numberFilesTextBox.Text = numFiles.ToString();

        //  Add ListBox items for the following string and its field
        numberFilesTypeListBox.Items.Add("Audio: " + numAudio);
        numberFilesTypeListBox.Items.Add("Image: " + numImage);
        numberFilesTypeListBox.Items.Add("Document: " + numDocument);
        numberFilesTypeListBox.Items.Add("Video: " + numVideo);
    }

    private void ReorganizeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  if the ComboBox text selected is "File Name" then organize in alphabetical order
        if (reorganizeComboBox.Text == "File Name")
        {
            //  Organize in alphabetical order
            filesListBox.Sorted = true;
        }
        else if (reorganizeComboBox.Text == "File Type")
        {

        }
        else if (reorganizeComboBox.Text == "File Size")
        {

        }
        else if (reorganizeComboBox.Text == "Last Modification Date")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should #1 create a parent class with the 3 properties you have to filter. Then your 4 classes (`Audio`,`Video`,`Document`,`Image`) should derive from that class. And finally you should not add to the `listbox` or `combobox` in the loop. Instead fill a `List<>` of type of the class you just created. Then you can easily sort that `List<>` the way you want and you loop on that sorted data to insert your items in the `listbox` and `combobox`

Answer (score 0):

If there's a class with all the properties and an `Enum` for sorting options, minimum example:

Class & Enum

```
class FileDescriptor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}, {Extension}, {Size}, {LastModified.ToString("yyyyMMd")}";
    }
}

enum SortEnum
{
    Name,
    Extension,
    Size,
    LastModified
}
```

The `ComboBox` has an event `SelectedIndexChanged` there the `ListBox` is sorted based on user selection:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Mockup for testing
    var files = new FileDescriptor[]
    {
        new FileDescriptor()
        {
            Name = "CarShow",
            Extension = "AVI",
            Size = 723,
            LastModified = DateTime.ParseExact("2019094", "yyyyMMd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        },
        new FileDescriptor()
        {
            Name = "FoodMenu",
            Extension = "PDF",
            Size = 200,
            LastModified = DateTime.ParseExact("20190214", "yyyyMMd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        },
        new FileDescriptor()
        {
            Name = "MathProblems",
            Extension = "TXT",
            Size = 13,
            LastModified = DateTime.ParseExact("2018053", "yyyyMMd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        }
    };
    var sortOptions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortEnum));

    this.lb_FileDescriptions.DataSource = files;
    this.cb_SortOptions.DataSource = sortOptions;
}

private void cb_SortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sortOption = (SortEnum)cb_SortOptions.SelectedValue;
    var files = lb_FileDescriptions.Items.Cast<FileDescriptor>();

    switch (sortOption)
    {
        case SortEnum.Name:
            lb_FileDescriptions.DataSource = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name)
                                                  .ToList();
            break;
        case SortEnum.Extension:
            lb_FileDescriptions.DataSource = files.OrderBy(f => f.Extension)
                                                  .ToList();
            break;
        case SortEnum.Size:
            lb_FileDescriptions.DataSource = files.OrderBy(f => f.Size)
                                                  .ToList();
            break;
        case SortEnum.LastModified:
            lb_FileDescriptions.DataSource = files.OrderBy(f => f.LastModified)
                                                  .ToList();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```